# ejabberd: Configuration for enable websocket communication for xmpp server

Tags: websocket, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, strophe

Im using Ejabberd 17.1.1. I need to configure my ejabberd.yml file for websocket communication. Im using strophe.js
I already had the configuration for ejabberd.yml ie,

```
 port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/api": mod_http_api
    ##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    ## register: true
    captcha: false
    http_bind: true
    tls: true
```

Also tried to get connection from my javascript code,

```
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('ws://localhost:5280/ws/', {protocol: "ws"});
    conn.connect($scope.jid, $scope.password, function(status, condition) {
        if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
...
```

when getting the

> status

its value is 1  not 5. what is the reason? I was able to connect the same one with 
*http://localhost:5280/bosh/* successfully.
Can any one give the correct configuration of ejbberd.yml file and sample code snippet for connecting through websocket using strophe.js. Thanks .

Comment: could you do console.log(status) and post here

Comment: actually in this case there is no importance of console.log. ie, No error happens here.the call back value of the status is "Connecting" .i want that status value as "Connected".

Comment: please try using connection url as :  'ws://127.0.0.1:5280/ws'